# No module named auth error in python web.py

Tags: python, authentication, web.py

I am using the Python web.py framework to design a small web application.

As indicated in the tutorial, when working with authorization I tried the following in the
Python interpreter:

```
In [10]: import web

In [11]: from web.contrib.auth import DBAuth
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/local/user/python_webcode/<ipython console> in <module>()

ImportError: No module named auth
```

But I am getting the above error. Can anyone please let me know how to solve this error and explain why it is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you do not have the auth module installed. I have assumed that the auth module you are trying to use the one at http://jpscaletti.com/webpy_auth/.

You've not indicated whether you installed web.py via easy_install or by running setup.py after downloading a tarball. In either case, I'd recommend that you:

1. Locate the web.py install folder
2. Download the auth module from the link above and extract the contents into the contrib/ folder of the web.py install folder